# Python pylibmc syntax / how can I use mc.set in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-memcached, pylibmc

I want to set keys in a for loop, and read them back in another script also using a loop.
To test memcache is working I made these simple scripts:

a.py

```
import pylibmc
mc = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1"], binary=True,
        behaviors={"tcp_nodelay": True,
        "ketama": True})
mc["key_1"] = "Value 1"
mc["key_2"] = "Value 2"
mc["key_3"] = "Value 3"
mc["key_4"] = "Value 4"
```

b.py:

```
import pylibmc
mc = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1"], binary=True,
        behaviors={"tcp_nodelay": True,
        "ketama": True})
print("%s" % (mc["key_1"]))
print("%s" % (mc["key_2"]))
print("%s" % (mc["key_3"]))
print("%s" % (mc["key_4"]))
```

This working fine. But I have no clue how to rewrite memcache line to be used in a for loop.
I tried several things, but nothing I tried did work.
What I want is something like this:

```
for index in range (0,4):
   mc["key_(index)"] = "Value (index)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use f-strings:

```
for index in range (0,4):
    key = f"key_{index}"
    mc[key] = f"{mc[key]} {index}" # or "Value {index}"
```